# How to render a video on image with AR.js keeping it perfectly in track and with the right size?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I implemented a simple video played over a recognized image, however the track system doesn't seem to be very automatic and the same it's about the rendered video size, compared with the original image frame.

How can I get a precise track and an automatic adjustment to match the video size with the ntf image?

Thanks in advance

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr    /aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js'>   </script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    AFRAME.registerComponent('videohandler', {
        init: function () {
            var marker = this.el;

            this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");

            marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function () {
                this.vid.play();
            }.bind(this));

    marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function() {
        this.vid.pause();
        this.vid.currentTime = 0;
    }.bind(this));
        }
    });
};
</script>

<style>
.arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
</div>
<a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer='antialias: true; alpha: true; precision: mediump;'
    embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

    <a-assets>
        <video src="assets/urobologio.mp4"
            preload="auto" id="vid" response-type="arraybuffer" loop
            autoplay autofocus playsinline>
        </video>
    </a-assets>

    <a-nft
        videohandler
        type='nft' url='nft/urobologio/urobologio-image/urobologio'

    >
        <a-video src="#vid" position="10 -10 -175" rotation="-90 0 0" width='140'     height='140'>
        </a-video>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: unluckily no; I must check the newest framework releases

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with the framework not returning correct dimensions and size of the tracked image. The devs are working on a fix, but it has been in development since May 2020. There is a way to do it in Three,js, but with marker only. The only other option which I managed to get working is 8thwall, they have an example on the website and it works perfectly fine, of course the issue with 8thwall is pricing.